# Actualizar Expresión Regular de un formulario google form dependiendo el valor de una celda

Tags: regex

Soy nuevo y no tengo casi conocimiento de programación, solo algo de macros en vba de excel por tanto entiendo un poco el funcionamiento, lo que necesito es que en una tabla voy agregando datos como el dni y luego quiero que cuando entran al formulario coloquen el dni para permitirle el acceso al mismo, entonces pensaba ir colocando un CONCATENAR con todos los dni que se encuentran en la base y colocarlo como  una expresión regular en el campo dni del formulario y que se actualice cada vez que entra un registro, es posible? Desde Ya muchas Gracias

Comment: HEBER Bienvenido, por favor debes aclarar en que lenguaje de programación estás trabajando, también colocarlo en las etiquetas de la pregunta, por favor lee [como hacer una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sí, es posible, aunque no sé si hay un máximo de caracteres en el campo de validación de Google Forms... Sería `dn1|dni2|dni3|etc`... ¿qué intentaste? porque así como estás preguntando, la única respuesta es "Sí, es posible"